# Enter key pressed fast

Tags: javascript, php

I am searching from around 5000 records. The search button is working fine. But when I press enter key too fast. It does not bring the result back. I tried codes from stckoverflow.com already but it's not working for me.

My textbox for search is

```
<input name="search_value" id="country_name"   onkeyup="Javascript: if (event.keyCode == 13) return false; searchFilter();"  />
```

Javascript for searchfilter()

```
function searchFilter()
{
    //alert("");
    $("#loader").show();
    var search_variable = $("#search_variable").val();
    var search_value = $("#country_name").val();
    //alert(search_value);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'searchorder.php?act=save&search_variable=' + search_variable + '&search_value=' + search_value,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            $("#loader").hide();
            $(".contentText").html(data);
            // $("#feedbackcommon"+act_id).show();
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="searchform"><?php echo SEARCH_TITLE; ?>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="search_variable" id="search_variable" onchange="checkvalue(this.value)" >
        <option value="rfq_id"><?php echo ORDER_ID; ?></option> 
        <option value="po_no"><?php echo PO_NO; ?></option>
        <option value="issue_no"><?php echo ISSUE_NO; ?></option>
        <option value="serial"><?php echo SERIAL_NO; ?></option>
        <option value="customers_firstname"><?php echo NAME_STORE; ?></option>
        
    </select>

    <input name="search_value" id="country_name"   onkeyup="Javascript: if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                searchFilter(); "  />
   
    <input type="button" name="Button" id="button" value="<?php echo SEARCH_BUTTON; ?>" class="myButton" onclick="searchFilter();" />
    <a href="allorders.php"><input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="<?php echo CLEAR_BUTTON; ?>" class="myButton" /></a>
    <div id="loader"><img src="images/opc-ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button to properly format code.

Comment: User JavaScript to disable your submit button once it's pressed.   That will prevent the double-click that is messing up your call.

Comment: @durbnpoisn that's a good idea, but you would need to check that the input field hasn't changed otherwise you only get one go. Hitting enter should also abort the previous request too.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes. That's used to put a script in attributes that normally contain a URL. But `onXXX` doesn't contain a URL, it contains a script, so you don't need to tell it that it's a script.

Comment: sorry its my first time i am asking question here.But how I can abort previous values?

Comment: To abort you would assign the request to a variable `var xhr = $.ajax(...` then use `if (xhr) xhr.abort();` before calling it again

Comment: it searches value but if i press enter slowly

Comment: sorry guys i dont have reputations to vote you but thanx for suggestions

Comment: Can you post more HTML or describe in more detail what should happen. The code you gave references more elements that you've shown.

Comment: Every edit you make wipes out the question. Add to the bottom!

Comment: It sounds like you need to either disable the submit button on submission, or use a leading-edge debounce on the submit function. http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/togr18Lb/1/

Ok, here's your solution.

Abort any previous requests when a new one is made so as not to flood the server with them.

Slow down the requests by waiting until the user stops typing.

The button works, so all we need to do is bind keyup and change of input field to trigger that button, rather than duplicate code. And we do this with jQuery, not using `onkeyup=""`.

To make sure we're not making unnecessary requests returning false when the enter key is pressed is correct, however we use `.preventDefault()` instead.

```
<input name="search_value" id="country_name"  />
```

jQuery

```
var searchFilterXhr;
var searchTimeout;

$(function(){
    // bind keyup (and change) to trigger the button that causes the search
    $('#country_name').on('keyup change', function(e){
        // prevent any default action, like submitting a form on enter.
        e.preventDefault();
        // if the text field has changed, only then do we search
        if ($(this).data('last-value') != $(this).val()) $('#button').trigger('click');
        // remember the previous value so that we can check it's changed
        $(this).data('last-value', $(this).val());

    });
});

function searchFilter(){
    //alert("");
    $("#loader").show();
    var search_variable = $("#search_variable").val();
    var search_value = $("#country_name").val();
    //alert(search_value);
    if (searchFilterXhr) searchFilterXhr.abort();
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        searchFilterXhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'searchorder.php?act=save&search_variable=' + search_variable + '&search_value=' + search_value,
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $("#loader").hide();
                $(".contentText").html(data);
                // $("#feedbackcommon"+act_id).show();
            }
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for this.I will apply this solution.Thanx all for answering my problem

Answer (score 1):

It is not supposed to return the results because you never start the `searchFilter`, if you use enter, you see `if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;`

keyCode 13 == ENTER, which means that u return false before `searchFilter();` gets called.
Remove the `if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;`

Comment: It searches on each keyup. Why then search again for the same request? Enter doesn't change the text in the field. Returning false before searching looks right.

Comment: It might look right, but for that case that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: if i remove "if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;" then how can i check when enter key pressed

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in jsfiddle?

Comment: @popnoodles sorry i can't

Comment: It searches the result if press enter slowly but if i press enter fast it does not bring results it just shows the page having all records

Comment: That was meant for @LauriOrgla

Answer (score 1):

You need use "promise timeout" like this:

```
var searchTimer  = null;
var searchInput  = $('#country_name');
var searchResult = $('.contentText');

searchInput.on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var val = $.trim(searchInput.val());
        if (val) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'searchorder.php?search_value=' + val,
                cache: false, // deny cache GET requests
                success: function(data) {
                    searchResult.html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 300);
});
```